# Django: Send HTML email via send_mass_mail()

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-views, django-email

It seems from the docs on email that HTML is supposed for `send_mail()` but not `send_mass_mail()`. Is my understanding correct, and if so is there a work-around to get the `send_mass_mail()` functionality with HTML without writing a custom loop?

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/email/

Comment: Found [this old question][1] that seems to remain valid...


  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7583801/send-mass-emails-with-emailmultialternatives

Answer (score 6):

You should check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10215091/2142093) where the guy creates a customized `send_mass_mail()` function that accepts HTML working with `EmailMultiAlternatives`