# send_mass_mail display link in email subject

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I use send_mass_mail and add to the message a link 
I get strange behavior: Some people will see the link as plain text other as link and some as half link half text, the link works when copy paste in the browser
Any suggestion how to fix it, it’s a big problem for me sending a link that doesn’t work?

for example:

[image]

Comment: Have you enclosed it in an `a` tag? (`<a href="http://example.com/link">my link</a>`)

Comment: @AshishNitinPatil I understood that send_mass_mail doesn’t support HTML - if I can use it as you mention how can I add it to a message text?   for exampe "Hi that is a text and here is a Link<a href="http://example.com/link">my link</a> ?

Comment: Can I use it in send_mass_mail as in the example?? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31715138/how-to-add-href-link-in-email-content-when-sending-email-through-smtplib

Comment: [Send HTML via send_mass_mail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26378008/django-send-html-email-via-send-mass-mail)

Comment: Thanks, so I need to add that code and create an HTML just to be able to view a link  as a link  in the subject?

Comment: In the email subject? Nope, you shouldn't have HTML in the subject (which the email reader would treat correctly). Subject links will be treated differently by different email readers, what you *can* do is add a trailing slash (`".../126/"`) which should hopefully resolve this issue.

Comment: @AshishNitinPatil thanks It could solve the broken link problem as I mention above but I dont think it will solve the plain text that some user get instead of link