# Sending mail chimp designed emails using django

Tags: django, email, mailchimp

I want to send a mail to the subscribers of a django website. So, as soon as someone registers they should be sent a mail. I can do this by the send_mail function that django has but I want to send a designed mail (like with a mail chimp template). Any ideas on how to do this? I read through the api documentation and understood how to send mails but I cannot understand how to integrate its own template and stuff.

Any advice will be helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MailChimp templates are just HTML. If you are using Django 1.7+, `send_email` supports `html_message`  [(ref)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/email/#send-mail).

You can use the `render_to_string` [(see here)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/templates/api/#the-render-to-string-shortcut) function to output the appropriate HTML, which will be fed into `send_email`. Combining these two, you can first set up your HTML template:

`html_template = render_to_string('templates/my_email.html', {'foo': 'bar'})`

Then create `my_email.html` and put the HTML generated on MailChimp into that file.

You can now call send_mail with the new HTML template:

```
send_mail(
    [...]
    html_message=html_template,
)
```

EDIT: Full example:

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.template.loader import render_to_string

html_template = render_to_string('templates/my_email.html', {'foo': 'bar'})
send_mail(
    'Title',
    'Plaintext Version Goes Here',
    'sender@sender.com',
    ['receiver@receiver.com'],
    html_message=html_template,
)
```

Comment: This is great! Thanks so much!

Comment: Quick follow up question - Would this work with `send_mass_mail()` as well?

Comment: Have a look at the answer over here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7583801/send-mass-emails-with-emailmultialternatives
Might answer your question!