# Django, sendmail password not from settings

Tags: django, python-3.x, sendmail

Im using Djangos sendmail and I wont use password from settings.

Current im using in settings

```
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'my Email'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'its secret'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
```

And in my view Im using:

```
from django.core.mail import EmailMultiAlternatives
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = current_user.profile.gmail_app_pass
EMAIL_HOST_USER = email_user = request.user.email
toaddr = 'to@email'
tocc = 'toCC@email'
user_bcc = 'toBCC@email'
subject = 'Test Email from Django'
msgHtml = '<p>This is an <strong>important</strong> message.</p>'            

msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, msgHtml, EMAIL_HOST_USER, [toaddr],  bcc=[user_bcc], cc=[tocc])
msg.attach_alternative(msgHtml, "text/html")
msg.send()
```

but how can I overwrite the settings from the settings? In my case EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD and EMAIL_HOST_USER

Im using Django 2.1 on Python 3.6

Comment: Essentially a duplicate of [send_mass_emails with EmailMultiAlternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7583801/1324033). Use `send_mass_mail` instead

Comment: How do you think you'd get the password into the system? Maybe an environment variable?

Comment: You shouldn't be doing this, it's a security risk to be storing other user's gmail credentials. Even if you ignore that risk, it will be difficult to get this to work. If you search Stack Overflow for gmail and Django, you will find users having problems sending email with *their own* gmail account. If you have multiple accounts then you'll have similar problems for multiple accounts.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the password on `.env` files. I recommend use [python decouple](https://github.com/henriquebastos/python-decouple) fot his work After you can retrieve the variable

**.env**

```
EMAIL_PASSWORD=Mypassword
EMAIL_USE_TLS=True
EMAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
....
```

**settings.py**

```
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = config('EMAIL_PASSWORD')
....
```