# creating bold text in mails sent by django send_mass_mail

Tags: python, django, email, sendmail

Django's `send_mass_mail` doesn't allow sending HTML mails, but I want to make a portion of the mail bold.

I tried:

```
    message= ("bla bla  '<b>%s</b>'."% title.title)
```

But as you can guess it escapes the tags in the mail. I wonder if there is a solution for that.

Comment: Can you show the end result please?

Answer (score 1):

Use `EmailMultiAlternatives` class

```py
from django.core.mail import EmailMultiAlternatives

subject, from_email = 'hello', 'from@example.com'
text_content = 'plain text body message.'
html_content = '<p>This is an <strong>alternative</strong> message using HTML.</p>'
msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, text_content, from_email, ['jhon@example.com', 'doe@example.com'])

msg.attach_alternative(html_content, "text/html")
msg.send()
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7583801/send-mass-emails-with-emailmultialternatives/10215091#10215091) can help too.

Comment: Does this one opens only one connection to send all the mails?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure. You can use the approach of the answer [added before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7583801/send-mass-emails-with-emailmultialternatives/10215091#10215091)

Comment: Thank you a lot.