# What is the best way to send dynamic HTML email to thousands of recipient with Django without any third party service?

Tags: python, django, email, django-models, django-rest-framework

I want to send email to thousands of users as quick as possible. I just want to confirm that the way I'm trying is good enough or not. What's the best way to do that?

Here is my code snippet:

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail, EmailMessage
from django.template import loader

def email_sender(email_object):
    subject = email_object["subject"]
    html_body = email_object["html_body"]
    from_email = email_object["from_email"]
    recipient_list = email_object["to_email"]

    if isinstance(recipient_list, str):
        recipient_list=[recipient_list]
    print("recipient_list :",recipient_list)

    html_message = loader.render_to_string(html_body,{})
    mail = EmailMessage(
        subject=subject,
        body=html_message, 
        from_email=from_email, 
        to=recipient_list
        )
    mail.content_subtype = "html"  # Main content is now text/html
    mail.send()
```

Comment: Did you even read the Django documentation? Django has something like `send_mass_email`. That would be a start, though a dedicated service is probably better (and less likely to have e-mail end up in a spam folder).

Comment: What is "dynamic html email"? What in particular do you mean by "dynamic"?

Comment: I have read about `send_mass_email` , I don't think so we can send HTML messages with that or can we ?

Comment: dynamic in a sense that we can render some context in email template.

Comment: Have you tried? It's easy to send a few test e-mails to (local/developer) test users. Try sending with send_mass_email, see if that works properly.

Comment: i just went to django docs and i didn't see any html_body parameter that we can pass in send_mass_email method

Comment: send_mass_mail(datatuple, fail_silently=False, auth_user=None, auth_password=None, connection=None)

Comment: And then the documentation of that function states that the datatuple contains items that are all 4-tuples of `(subject, message, from_email, recipient_list)`. With an example to follow. How does that not work for you?

Comment: I didn't try that because there wasn't clearly mentioned that we can pass html message. That is way i didn't try that..

Comment: Have a look at e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7583801/send-mass-emails-with-emailmultialternatives/10215091#10215091 or search around.